# Why doesn't unity show icons or panel after installing numix theme?

Tags: unity, compiz

I'm a beginner to Ubuntu/Linux and I have a problem: Unity is not loading! When I choose Unity in the log-in screen, I get notifications and I can see the mouse, but that's it.

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed, along with Bumblebee/Primus. I had no issues whatsoever, until I decided to try the numix-theme and the numix icon pack. I added the PPA and installed it, but when I logged off and logged back on, nothing showed up. I panicked, and in tty1, I purged numix-* but that did not solve the issue.

To get by day-to-day use, I installed gnome-flashback, and among those environments, only the metacity one works. (The compiz one does not.) I've tried installing the unity-tweak-tool to reset unit, installing dconf and doing:

```
dconf reset -f /org/compiz/
```

but that didn't work either. One site even told me to delete `/org/compiz/`, but that did not resolve the issue.

When I checked `ccsm`, the Unity plugin had a check to it.

I also tried with [Unity doesn't load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears), but it gets stuck on "loading icons".

Any help will be awesome!

Comment: @Sid Did you try purging Bumblebee/Primus ?

Comment: @Venki I didn't, but I didn't have an issue using it. Even now, in metacity-ubuntu-flashback, it works fine. I kind of get the feeling that I accidentally deleted the Unity icons/ config, but I'm not too sure. Do you really think purging bumblebee/primus will work?

Comment: @Sid I will admit that I dunno much about Bumblebee/Primus... but what i guess is.. when you did a sudo apt-get update while installing numix something got updated and now your Bumblebee/Primus driver ain't supporting that update...but just a guess. Thats why I am not putting it out as an answer. So try purging Bumblebee/Primus at your own risk.

Comment: okay. I was foolish in saying 'something got updated' . Did you use software updater or did apt-get upgrade after installing numix and before rebooting your PC? If yes, then try purging Bumblebee/primus and reinstalling Compiz(since you said you purged it in your description above).

Comment: @Venki okay, I'll give it a shot. Do I use this command to install compiz? 
sudo apt-get install compiz compizconfig-settings-manager compiz-fusion-plugins-extra compiz-fusion-plugins-main compiz-plugins

Comment: Well, sudo apt-get install compiz will do...

Comment: @Venki, it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have intel hd graphics, try to install the intel drivers. I had installed drivers from "xorg-edgers" ppa until now. I needed to purge that ppa and their packages, downgrade the drivers to the ubuntu built-in and then install the Intel new drivers for 14.04 LTS for have unity working again.

Comment: I don't want to mess up anything more than I have already :P Could you walk me through it? 
I've already copied my home folder. I'm really close to a fresh install.